# Path for running Python files

Tags: python, path

I have a directory which I would like to be the default for Python scripts so when a user is running `python foo.py arg1 arg2` and `foo.py` is not in the current directory, it should execute `python /defaultdir/foo.py arg1 arg2`. Neither `$PATH` nor `$PYTHONPATH` is good for that: the first would only work with the command `foo.py arg1 arg2`, which requires a hashbang in the script and execution rights, while the second only works for `import`˙commands from an already running script. I suppose I could replace the Python binary with a wrapper, but I would prefer a cleaner solution if there was one.

Comment: I’m afraid what you want is unreasonable.

Comment: the last alternative (replacing python binary) seems to be the best you presented. Anyway you'll need to tinker with some system aspect or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [python -m](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-m):

```
python -mfoo arg1 arg2
```

Comment: did you mean `python -m foo arg1 arg2`?

Comment: Well color me impressed, it certainly looks like it.